# Python patching FTP import

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I'm trying to write a unit test for my ftp downloader. For some reason my import isn't patched. I can see while debugging the ftp object is a real FTP object instead of a mocked one. I'm using Python 3.5 with pytest.

here is my code:

```
from ftplib import FTP
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock


class FTPDownloader:
    def get_listing(self, host,user, password):
        ftp = FTP()
        ftp.connect(host)
        ftp.login(user, password)
        return ftp.nlst('/')


class TestMyAwesomeTest:

    @patch('ftplib.FTP', autospec=True)
    def test_get_listing(self, mock_ftp_constructor):
        mock_ftp = mock_ftp_constructor.return_value
        mock_ftp.nlst = MagicMock(return_value=['abc.csv'])
        ftp_downloader = FTPDownloader()
        listing = ftp_downloader.get_listing('ftp://foo.bar', 'user', 'password')
        assert listing == ['abc.csv']
```

when i run this my error is:

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

how can i fix my test/patch to run successfully?
Thanks a lot for your help!

-edit-
my file is located in:
`tagging/tests/unit/test_my_awesome_test.py`

if i change the patch to: `@patch('tagging.tests.unit.test_my_awesome_test.FTP', autospec=True)` it's still not working with the same error

Comment: If you use `from ftlib import FTP` you have to patch that instance (see [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6)). Alternatively, you `import ftplib` and use `ftplib.FTP`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here that you are patching a class in the same file. The default approach as mentioned in [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6) works for source files separate from the test files (the usual case). If you have the source in the same file as the test, you can use `patch.object` with the current module instead:

```py
class TestMyAwesomeTest:

    @patch.object(sys.modules[__name__], 'FTP', autospec=True)
    def test_get_listing(self, mocked_ftp):
        mocked_ftp.return_value.nlst.return_value = ['abc.csv']
        ftp_downloader = FTPDownloader()
        listing = ftp_downloader.get_listing('ftp://foo.bar', 'user', 'password')
        assert listing == ['abc.csv']
```